# How to set HTTP status text in PHP server

Tags: php, apache, http, webserver

I am facing an issue here.
I want to set status text with status code for response from PHP server and I am able to do that perfectly on local PHP server by using

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("HTTP/1.1 200 Successfully Retrieved Data");
echo json_encode($response);
```

By using the above code on local server I am getting

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Successfully Retrieved Data
```

But when I am using same code on a real server then its just showing

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The status message is getting overridden by OK.
Not sure whats wrong here. I tried this another real server also but still same issue but it works perfectly fine on local server (WAMP)

Some more information:
My local server PC is Windows 10 with WAMP 3 and Apache 2
Real Server 1: CentOS 8 and Apache 2
Real Server 2: CentOS 7 and Apache 2

Comment: status codes are sent by the server , you can not set them by program.

Comment: Well in PHP we can do that. The above code works perfectly fine on local server but it's giving problem in real hosted php server